# R to C++ code to loop through list of data frames (Rcpp)

Tags: c++, rcpp

I have a list of data frames and I want to loop through the columns of each data frame within the list to create new variables using c++ code (as I'm learning Rcpp).

The input will look like:

```
 $`df1`
 a  b  c
 5 30  2
 4  2 15
 3  2 17

$df2
a  b  c
5 30  2
4  2 15
3  2 17
```

Ideally, the output would be:

```
    $`df1`
    a     b     c
    5.02 30.02  2
    4.15 2.15   15
    3.17 2.17   17

    $df2
    a     b      c
    5.02  30.02  2
    4.15  2.15   15
    3.17  2.17   17
```

I would like to drop column c afterwards, but right now I'm trying to figure out the c++ code for doing this.

NOTE: I want the 2 in column C row 1 to come in as 02 and not 20 when it's pasted on (so they're all same width and it's accurate).

Comment: Why do this outside of `R` *at all*?

Comment: Your two data-frame examples are *exactly the same*. I don't see why you get "5.20 30.02". Are you intending to do different operations to your different columns?

Comment: @Caleth thanks for getting back to me! I'm going outside of R because with larger lists with larger data.frames R is extremely slow (even after vectorization and parellelization (I'll be scaling this up). I've done both, and while I got speed improvements, it just remains too slow for the job I need. But maybe there is something in R that can be done that you know about?

Comment: @Caleth Also, I just made a quick example of a list of data.frames for illustration purposes, so here they are the same. In reality, the data.frame elements within my list will be different. And the 5.20 30.02 is a typo, good catch! Sorry about that (fixed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but here some quick and dirty code to loop over the columns in a list of data frames:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List listDf(Rcpp::List l) {
  for (int i = 0; i < l.length(); ++i) {
    Rcpp::DataFrame df = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::DataFrame>(l[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < df.cols(); ++j) {
      Rcpp::NumericVector col = df[j];
      df[j] = 1.23 * col;
    }
  }
  return l;
}

/*** R
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(a = sample(1:100, 3),
                  b = sample(1:100, 3),
                  c = sample(1:100, 3))

df2 <- data.frame(a = sample(1:100, 3),
                  b = sample(1:100, 3),
                  c = sample(1:100, 3))

l <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)

listDf(l)

*/
```

And if you actually want to add 1/100 of the last column to the other columns, you can use:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List listDf(Rcpp::List l) {
  for (int i = 0; i < l.length(); ++i) {
    Rcpp::DataFrame df = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::DataFrame>(l[i]);
    Rcpp::NumericVector last = df[df.cols() - 1];
    for (int j = 0; j < df.cols() - 1; ++j) {
      Rcpp::NumericVector col = df[j];
      df[j] = col + last / 100.0;
    }
  }
  return l;
}

/*** R
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(a = sample(1:100, 3),
                  b = sample(1:100, 3),
                  c = sample(0:99, 3))

df2 <- data.frame(a = sample(1:100, 3),
                  b = sample(1:100, 3),
                  c = sample(0:99, 3))

l <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)

listDf(l)

*/
```

Output:

```
> listDf(l)
$df1
      a     b  c
1 92.73 84.73 73
2 93.13 64.13 13
3 29.64 51.64 64

$df2
       a     b  c
1  71.94 94.94 94
2  46.96 26.96 96
3 100.11 46.11 11
```

Comment: so there's something funny going on, soon as the number of elements goes beyond 2 with an R do.call("list",....) function to create a bigger list, the digits change and a and b look different, why is this?

Comment: @zeekster26 I don’t follow your description. Ca you provide a minimal example?

Comment: So in R use df1 <- data.frame(a = sample(1:100, 3),
                  b = sample(1:100, 3),
                  c = sample(0:99, 3))
then make a list of objects as follows: dsets<-do.call("list", replicate(100, x, simplify=FALSE)) and create, say, 100 (this is just as a quick easy example, the data sets wont be exactly the same across the list in real life). Now when you run the listDf(dsets) function it will paste incorrectly and the a and b columns values will be off (almost as if it's factoring in the numbe rof elements in the list or something).

Comment: Sorry, use this: dsets<-do.call("list", replicate(100, df1, simplify=FALSE)) to create 100 df1 sets

Answer (score 0):

@Ralf Stubner figured I'd give you a visual

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = sample(1:100, 3), b = sample(1:100, 3), c = sample(0:99, 3))
```

gives (didn't set.seed):

```
  df1
  a  b  c
  28 70 70
  14 63  5
   8 12 20

dsets<-do.call("list", replicate(10, df1, simplify=FALSE)) #to replicate this 10 times 
#and store as list
```

Run this

```
       listDf(dsets)
```

And output is as follows:

```
[[9]]
  a    b  c
35.0 77.0 70
14.5 63.5  5
10.0 14.0 20

[[10]]
  a    b  c
35.0 77.0 70
14.5 63.5  5
10.0 14.0 20
```

Probably something simple I'm missing?

Comment: So I discovered that it adds a+(c/100) for one iteration then goes and adds c/100 again to the result of a+(c/100) prior, so it does factor in the elements of the list. Same for column b. I don't know how to fix this, though.

Comment: This is a result of R's memory management using "copy on write", i.e. if you create a "copy", e.g. via `rep`, than this is only a reference. But before you write to the object, a copy is made. This is lost when you go to C++. Your list `dsets` contains ten references to the same object, which are then manipulated in place. If you create a list of ten different data frames, then it works as expected.